# I have an onload="setDate();" in the <body> tag of the html doc. Why is it not populating Day, Month and year with my Js file?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my Javascript code.

```
function setDate() {
    var today = new Date();

    document.getElementById("myday").value = today.getDate();
    document.getElementById("mymonth").value = today.getMonth();
    document.getElementById("myyear").value = today.getYear();
}
```

What is wrong with my syntax? I am trying to populate my values with the js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Aptana</title>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/calendar.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/task.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/calendar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/task.css">
</head>
<body onload="setDate();">
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="leftdiv">
<div id="topleft">
    <form>
    Day: &nbsp; 
    <input type="number" min="1" max="31" step="1" name="myday">
    Month: &nbsp; 
    <select name="mymonth">
        <option value="0">January</option>
        <option value="1">Febuary</option>
        <option value="2">March</option>
        <option value="3">April</option>
        <option value="4">May</option>
        <option value="5">June</option>
        <option value="6">July</option>
        <option value="7">August</option>
        <option value="8">September</option>
        <option value="9">October</option>
        <option value="10">November</option>
        <option value="11">December</option>
    </select>

    Year: &nbsp;
    <input type="number" min="100" max="2016" name="myyear">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="bottomleft">
</div>
</div>

<div id="rightdiv">
<div id="topright">
</div>
<div id="bottomright">
</div>
</div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Could someone help me with this. I am trying to get today's day, month, and year from my js file to populate in my html file in chrome.

Comment: What problem do you see?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the elements in your HTML really have those id values?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant HTML too?

Comment: Look at the developer console and check for the errors. It is impossible to help you with the information you provided. Show all the code.

Answer (score 1):

`.value` will work if you are populating input fields:

```
<input id="myday" />
<script>
  document.getElementById('myday').value = 'foo'
</script>
```

though if you are trying to set the value of a text node, you'll want to use something like `.innerText`:

```
<p id="myday"></p>
<script>
  document.getElementById('myday').innerText = 'foo'
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `.value` you can using `.innerHTML` to set the value, or to get the value. :D

try this code snippet:

```js
function setDate() {
    var today = new Date();

    document.getElementById("myday").innerHTML = today.getDate();
    document.getElementById("mymonth").innerHTML = today.getMonth();
    document.getElementById("myyear").innerHTML = today.getFullYear();
}

setDate(); //set this to your onload body
```

```html
<p id="myday"></p>
<p id="mymonth"></p>
<p id="myyear"></p>
```

Comment: Here is my html doc. If anyone has any suggestions please feel free to help. It would be greatly appreciated.